# What's the proper cable to connect this power station to a solar panel?

Tags: solar-power, solar

My uncle gave me his old 1000w portable power station. I already have a Bluetti SP120 portable solar panel that has mc4 connectors. I'd like to use this to the power station. I tried googling it to no avail. I also tried google lens and it didn't yield any meaningful result.

Here's a photo of the port that the power station has that'll accept solar:
[image]

here's the spec sheet if it helps:

[image]

another picture for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If it's a standard plug it seems likely to be a "2 pin cannon female plug" similar to this, but with the two pins in a slightly different position and a screw lock. I see variants online that may well fit, but the ones with the pins in the right position have incompatible shrouds. I suggest sitting on a site like element14 or rscomponents browsing the list of circular two pin connectors until you find something that looks plausible, assuming you can't contact the manufacturer and ask (or just buy their cable assuming it's affordably priced).

[image: two pin audio style cannon plug]

Comment: I've finally found it locally.. thank you for those who helped! it cost about $2.50 - [store listing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIl9m.jpg)